# How to make Visual Studio Code show errors when using missing SCSS styles in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, scss-lint

In my React app I import styles from a SCSS file like this:

```
import styles from './index.module.scss';
```

To use a particular SCSS style I set up a className on a component and grab a style from a styles array:

```
<span className={styles['product-price__sign--negative']}>
```

When I will make a typo in the class name like this:

```
<span className={styles['product-price__sign--neg']}>
```

There is no SCSS style of this type in the styles file.
In this case, Visual Studio Code should show an error indicating I am trying to use a style that is missing.

However, it does not happen, and I don't see any warning or error.

What to do to make Visual Studio Code show a warning/error when I am using a style that is missing in the SCSS file when coding with React ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install eslint module and this package:
[eslint-plugin-react-css-modules](https://github.com/Bwca/eslint-plugin-react-css-modules)
It shows you if your scss classes doesn't exist

Comment: The package seems like exactly what I need. Do you know any alternative for tslint?

Comment: I don't know any package of this sort for tslint, but you should move from tslint to eslint because it is now deprecated: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/tslint-eslint-migration

Comment: I have switched from tslint to eslint, and installed the extension. However it does not work

Comment: Did you create your .eslintrc.json file in your repo with the necessary data? Otherwise, i'm sorry but i won't be able to help you on this

Comment: Maybe you could use the default creat-react-app with typescript .eslintrc.json and add the plugin and the rule in it

Comment: I have migrated from tslint, .eslint... was created automatically. I have added the plugin and the rule, but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Will this extension help ? - [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-scss]

Comment: I have SCSS IntelliSense installed. But it does not help